# Check & Modify /etc/fstab

Tags: bash, shell-script, fstab

at every boot of my system I should check the file "/etc/fstab":

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
#/dev/disk/by-partlabel/userdata    /userdata    ext4    defaults    0    2
#/dev/disk/by-partlabel/oem         /oem         ext4    defaults    0    2
```

and if the lines:

- /dev/disk/by-partlabel/userdata
- /dev/disk/by-partlabel/oem

start with '#' (comment), remove the comment and reboot the system

I make a simple batch that removes the '#' for each line, starting from the line number 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if the WiFi driver will be loaded
echo -e "\n\r##############################"
echo -e "#  Start reading /etc/fstab  #"
echo -e "##############################\n\r"

cat /etc/fstab

# Backup the original file
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak

# Remove '#' starting from the second line
sed -i '2,3s/#//' $fstabConfigPath
```

Since in future, the file /etc/fstab could contain other lines, I would like to improve the script to remove the '#' only for the specified lines.

Thank you for the help,
Federico

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix whatever is adding the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather that pointing at numbered lines, you should ask `sed` to operate only on lines that match a pattern.  Here's a way you could do that:

```
sed -ri.bak '/^#[/]dev[/]disk[/]by-partlabel[/](userdata|oem)( |\t)/ s/^#//' /etc/fstab
```

There's no need to copy the file, you can tell `sed -i` to create it for you by giving it the extension you want it to have.

### Checking if the file was actually modified before rebooting.

```
diff -q /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak || reboot
```

## Warning

Automatically editing `/etc/fstab` and rebooting seems a bit risky -- if something goes wrong you could find your system rendered un-bootable.

Comment: Thank you @bxm! It works like a charm. The /etc/fstab contains two partition used to mount a wifi driver that are commented after each upgrade. So, in order to use the WiFi, I must remove the comment at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Is there a way to know if the script modified the fstab? I need to know if the file was modified in order to trigger a reboot. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with one of many possible methods for checking if the file was updated.